# Acces foreign library from cabal2nix in andother derivation

Tags: haskell, ffi, nix

I'm building Haskell foreign library using nix with cabal2nix. After build `./result/` directory contains `libroman.so` under `/lib/ghc-8.8.4/` subdirectory.

When trying to use it in another derivation (qt one in my case) it is not visible by the linker.

Haskell nix:

```hs
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in

pkgs.haskellPackages.callCabal2nix "roman" ./. {}
```

Qt nix:

```hs
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  romanEngine = import ../engine/default.nix;
in

pkgs.qt5.mkDerivation {
  name = "roman-gui";
  src = ./.;

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    pkgs.qt5.qmake
  ];

  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.qt5.qtbase
    romanEngine
  ];
}
```

Linker error:

```
/nix/store/b10shv9yqbgps47y0n8x7l7bq8fmp1i6-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: cannot find -lroman
```

**How can I link correctly to foreign library I have build?**

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but might lead toward a solution.

`stdenv` will configure the linker to look in `<storepath>/lib`. Perhaps you could symlink your libs into there?

```hs
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  inherit (pkgs.haskell.lib) overrideCabal;
  generatedPkg = pkgs.haskellPackages.callCabal2nix "roman" ./. {};
in

overrideCabal generatedPkg (
  drv: {
    postInstall = (drv.postInstall or "") + ''
      ln -s $out/lib/ghc-*/* $out/lib
      # or something similar to make the libs available where the linker
      # expects them
    '';
  }
)
```